# SQL - Select Field to write depending on record

Tags: sql, ms-access

the following code works as intended:

```
SELECT Sessions.*, Register.EmailAddress AS TeamleadAddress
FROM Register, Employees INNER JOIN Sessions ON Employees.EmpNumber =  Sessions.EmpNumber
WHERE (((Register.Username)=[Employees].[Teamlead]));
```

There's another column I need to the same query though:

```
Register.EmailAddress AS QualityAddress WHERE ((Register.Username)=[Employees].[Quality]));
```

Sadly I don't really can figure it by myself... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional `JOIN` to `Register`.  In MS Access, this also requires a bunch of parentheses:

```
SELECT s.*, rtl.EmailAddress AS TeamleadAddress, rq.EmailAddress
FROM ((Sessions as s LEFT JOIN
       Employees as e
       ON e.EmpNumber = s.EmpNumber
      ) LEFT JOIN
      Register as rtl
      ON rtl.UserName = e.Teamlead
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Register as rq
     ON rq.UserName = e.Quality;
```

This uses `LEFT JOIN`, so if one of the columns is `NULL` in `Employees`, then the query will still return the row.

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon! Works like a charm with a small typo correction (ON etl. = On e.). Can't correct the typo as it's less than x characters that SO wants me to change. Thanks again!